# Is 'return' necessary in the last line of JS function?

Tags: javascript, function

What's the best practice for finishing a JavaScript function if it doesn't return anything?

```js
function foo(a) {
    if (a) {
        setTimeout()
    }

    return;
}
```

In this case `return` is unnecessary but I leave it for readability purposes. I also tried to google if this is a way to micro-optimize JS but wasn't able to find anything.

Comment: if it doesn't return anything then you don't need the return statement. it doesn't make anything faster by putting it there.

Comment: In my opinion removing the `return` makes it more readable, since you don't need it at all.

Comment: If you ran that code through a minifier, it would remove that `return;`. Therefore it is not an optimization of any kind. If you must keep it, do be sure to include the terminating semicolon because of automatic semicolon insertion rules. See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) for more information.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> what's the best practice of finishing the JS function if it doesn't
> return anything?

A function returns `undefined` by default. The use of `return` is therefore only *necessary* if you want to override the default behaviour.

---

**Why most leave it out when they can**

The Javascript community seem to dislike unnecessary verbose code. It might even be said to be a sport to make the code as short and compact as possible.

**Why this may not be the best practice for all**

The habit of always using return may serve as a good reminder that a function *always returns something* and thereby remind you to reflect on whether the default behaviour should be overridden.

However an experienced programmer will have such considerations deeply internalized and therefore rarely have need for such reminders.

**Conclusion**

As one gains experience the sport for less verbose code intensifies and in that context writing code just confirming default behaviour is an absolute no-go.

So: in the long run I would say most people end up leaving it out and that it is justified to do so because of the high degree of internalization.

Comment: Actually, in really old JavaScript implementations, the default return value was the result of the last expression which later was deemed unsafe and was replaced by "undefined". (C/C++ void functions still return EAX/RAX with whatever "random" value that register is assigned to at the time of the RET instruction...)

Answer (score 10):

No, a `return` statement is not necessary at the end of a void function (sorry for the C-terms there). If you want to exit a function early, however (say if a specific condition wasn't met), then you'll use a `return` statement, even if you're not returning a value.

Including a return statement at the end of a void function for readability, should be fine. I honestly don't think doing so is going to add much to your footprint.

**In my opinion**, however, you shouldn't include a return statement at the end of a function that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Note that the `Void` type exists in JavaScript... However, I don't think it applies to functions that don't return anything.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun and FYI I wrote a little benchmark script to try it out.

To my surprise, the one with the return statement returned faster than the one without by about 100ms for about a dozen runs on Firefox (Gecko). This result was pretty consistent on both Mac and Ubuntu.

I also ran it on Chrome (WebKit) and the results were much more ambiguous, there wasn't much consistency at all.

These were my results and are in no way definitive. Feel free to try it for yourself. In my opinion your personal preference is more relevant than 100ms anyway. If that's how you roll, then add it.

```
function f1(){
    console.log("doing stuff 1");
}

function f2(){
    console.log("doing stuff 2");
    return;
}

var start = (new Date()).getTime();
var i = 1000; while(i--) f1();
var time1 = (new Date()).getTime() - start;

var start = (new Date()).getTime();
var i = 1000; while(i--) f2();
var time2 = (new Date()).getTime() - start;

console.log("Without return: "+time1);
console.log("With return: "+time2);
```

[Here's a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/7f5u72vr/)

Comment: The results of your JSFiddle seem completely random. Sometimes the function with no return statement executes faster (according to your timing), and other times the function *with* the return statement runs faster. I don't think this information is accurate enough to form a solid conclusion.

Comment: i agree brynden. benchmarking is generally not reliable with javascript since there are so many different interpreters and versions.. however, on my set up, FF on mac, the one with a return came back first every time.

Answer (score 3):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (search for `Remove the body brackets and word "return" -- the return is implied`) which body is a single line and without curly braces do not require a `return` statement, even for non `void` functions. Example.

```
var returnTest = () => 1 + 1;
returnTest(); // Outputs 2

var returnTest2 = () => { 1 + 1};
returnTest2(); // Outputs undefined
```

AFAIK and aside from `void` functions, this is the only instance in which `return` may be ommitted.

Comment: This is correct, but pretty annoying. Ruby has ruined me, since it always auto-returns the last value on the stack. I wish returnTest2 would just error out when trying to transpile from Typescript, but alas ...

Answer (score 2):

As the other people have stated, its not necessary. But some people find it good practice. especially when you love being declarative and you know return statement is nothing more than actually a `GOTO` statement. (think of your programming being completly linear and you can only move between code with labels and goto statements). This way you always declare where you are going to: you are going back.

### Another reason to return void

For example you can have the following function

```
function login(user, pass){
  if(user === null)
    return;
  doTheRest(user, pass);
}
```

This way in a void method you can return 'early' to make sure you dont continue when a condition is not made. This is whats also called defensive programming.

note: most of the time your better of throwing an error `throw new Error(...)` instead. This way you realise earlier you forgot to match a pre-condition.

Answer (score 2):

Adding an unnecessary `return` statement won't make any real difference in terms of optimization. Write code for humans and not computers.

It's not need if you won't use function to get a result (i.e. `sum(2, 3)`), such as:

```
function xxx(){
  post().then(function(){
    location.href('http://stackoverflow.com');
  }, function(){
    showError();
  });
}
```

You see I have 3 functions and all have not `return` statement, and it's just fine.

Entering in opinion lands, I would say that you *could* leave it for your readability and comfort, but you would have an approach different from most of programmers. And as less is better (KISS), and if it's not necessary at all, it's better to omit it.

PS: The result of a function without `return`, will be `undefined`, naturally.

```
 function a(param){
   var x = param;
 }
 function b(param){
   var x = param;
   return;
 }
 function c(param){
   var x = param;
   return x;
 }
 a(5); // undefined
 b(5); // undefined
 c(5); // 5
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `return` statement but it's good practice to use `void` operator which force the function keyword to be treated as an expression instead of a declaration.

But then your function should look like that:

```
void function (a) {if (a) {setTimeout()}}
```

If you declare a non-immediately-invoked function expression, your should:

- `return true`

or

- `return !failure;`

Comment: we don't specify function return types in javaSCRIPT.

Comment: According to [MDM JavaScript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)  it's correct to define return type of function.

Comment: void is a js operator and has nothing to do with functions. in java for example void is a function modifier, not just an operator that can be put there if the dev feels like it. not the same thing.

Comment: It isnt really used in front of a function, its more often used in links `<a href="javascript:void(...);"`

Comment: It can be used to force the function keyword to be treated as an expression instead of a declaration. So it's  operator.